# Chosing the right index for PostgreSQL query

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-8.4

Simplified table:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
sales integer,
status varchar(16),
category varchar(16));

CREATE INDEX index_products_sales ON products (sales);
CREATE INDEX index_products_status ON products (status);
CREATE INDEX index_products_category ON products (category);
```

PostgreSQL version is 8.4. Columns 'status' and 'category'

There are 20 million products/rows spread across 15 categories.

One of the most used queries is getting the three most sold products, excluding products in categories 'cat3' and 'cat7':

```
SELECT product_no, sales 
FROM products 
WHERE status = 'something' AND category NOT IN ('cat3', 'cat7') 
ORDER BY sales DESC 
LIMIT 3;

Limit  (cost=0.00..8833.39 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=9235.332..9356.284 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index_products_sales on products  (cost=0.00..68935806.85 rows=23412 width=12) (actual time=9235.327..9356.278 rows=3 loops=1)
     Filter: (((category)::text <> ALL ('{cat3,cat7}'::text[])) AND ((status)::text = 'something'::text))
```

What would be the best index for making this specific query run faster?

Comment: CREATE INDEX index_special ON products (status, sales DESC NULLS LAST) WHERE NOT (category = 'cat3' and category = 'cat7');

Comment: @jug: The `WHERE` condition of the index is logically wrong, all rows qualify this way because no row can match both categories at the same time. I added an answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: You're right, of course.

Answer (score 13):

Create a partial, multicolumn index with this particular sort order:

```
CREATE INDEX products_status_sales_partial_idx ON products (status, sales DESC)
WHERE  category NOT IN ('cat3','cat7');
```

Modify your query slightly:

```
SELECT product_no, sales 
FROM   products 
WHERE  status = 'something'
AND    category NOT IN ('cat3', 'cat7') 
ORDER  BY status, sales DESC 
LIMIT  3;
```

Adding `status` as first element of the `ORDER BY` clause seems redundant and pointless. But give it a try.

#### Why?

The query planner is not smart enough to understand, that with

```
WHERE  status = 'something' ...
ORDER  BY sales DESC
```

the sort order of the index `(status, sales DESC)` matches as a logical consequence. So it is going to read *all* qualifying rows, sort and pick the top 3.

By adding `status` to the `ORDER BY` you enable the query planner to read the top 3 entries from the index directly. Expect a speed-up by **several orders of magnitude**.

Tested with PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

I think a b-tree index is still your best bet. I could be wrong, though. I think I would test two things.

First, a partial index on category that excludes 'cat3' and 'cat7'.

```
CREATE INDEX index_products_category ON products (category)
  WHERE category NOT IN ('cat3','cat7');
```

Second, a descending sort on sales.

```
CREATE INDEX index_products_sales ON products (sales DESC);
```

Either one of these might slow down other queries, though, so you might need one or both of these *in addition* to the existing indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but should it really say "(category = 'cat3' **and** category = 'cat7')" in the WHERE NOT-clause?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, and I'm not sure why I wrote anything like that WHERE clause in the first place. I should have been awake by that time. `WHERE category NOT IN ('cat3','cat7')` is how I'd normally think. Here, on a table of a million rows, this runs to completion in about .06ms.